# Create new column with conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which are:

```
                Value
    Date
2010-06-29        3
2010-06-30        1
2010-07-01        5
2010-07-02        4
2010-07-03        9
2010-07-04        7
2010-07-05        2
2010-07-06        3
```

```
                Value
    Date
2010-06-29        6
2010-07-03        1
2010-07-06        4
```

The first dataframe could be created with the Python code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date': ['2010-06-29', '2010-06-30', '2010-07-01', '2010-07-02', '2010-07-03', '2010-07-04', '2010-07-05', '2010-07-06'], 
        'Value': [3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 7, 2, 3]
    }
)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

and the second dataframe:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date': ['2010-06-29', '2010-07-03', '2010-07-06'], 
        'Value': [6, 1, 4]
    }
)

df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.date
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')
```

I want to create a second column in the first dataframe and the value of each ***Date*** in the new column will be the value of the first ***Date*** in the second dataframe equal to or earlier than the ***Date*** in the first dataframe.

So, the output is:

```py
                Value   Value_2
    Date
2010-06-29        3        6
2010-06-30        1        6
2010-07-01        5        6
2010-07-02        4        6
2010-07-03        9        1
2010-07-04        7        1
2010-07-05        2        1
2010-07-06        3        4
```

Also, it is my priority not to use any for-loops for the code.

How can I do this?

Comment: `pd.merge_asof` might be helpful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.merge_asof` should suffice for this

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)

pd.merge_asof(df, df2, on='Date')

        Date  Value_x  Value_y
0 2010-06-29        3        6
1 2010-06-30        1        6
2 2010-07-01        5        6
3 2010-07-02        4        6
4 2010-07-03        9        1
5 2010-07-04        7        1
6 2010-07-05        2        1
7 2010-07-06        3        4
```